# R distribution plot with NA data and thresholds

Tags: r, dataframe, distribution

I have a large data file in the form:

```
Input_SNP   Set_1    Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5     Set_6
1.09        0.162    NA        2.312     1.876     0.12      0.812
0.687       NA       0.987     1.32      1.11      1.04      NA
NA          1.890    0.923     1.43      0.900     2.02      2.7
2.801       0.642    0.791     0.812     NA        0.31      1.60
1.33        1.33     NA        1.22      0.23      0.18      1.77
2.91        1.00     1.651     NA        1.55      3.20      0.99
2.00        2.31     0.89      1.13      1.25      0.12      1.55
```

I would like to make a distribution of the totals in each column that are over 2.0. For example, Set_1 > 2 = 1, Set_2 > 2 = 0, Set_3 > 2 = 1. The issue is that each column has a "random" amount of missing data (NA). So that messes up the distribution. It seems my only option is to do a distribution of percentages. For example: Set_1 > 2 = 1/6, Set_2 > 2 = 0/5, Set_3 > 2 = 1/6. I would like to make a distribution of these percentages into a bell-curve of binned histogram. Despite my example, the percentages in each column over 2 should be between 0.00% and 3.00% so bins of size 0.05 would be nice. I would then like to plot my Input_SNP percentage on that distribution to get a p-value. Do you guys know how to do this in R? Currently this is in both a data.frame file and a .csv?

I had been trying: `hist(colSums(as.matrix(df) > 2))` but that had not been working (I think because of the NAs). So how can I incorporate that?

My desired output is a histogram of percentages of each column that is over 2. The bins in the histogram can be 0.05.

Comment: What part are you stuck on exactly? Have you attempted any code at all? You seem to just be asking someone to code this for you which isn't exactly how this site works. Try to ask one clear, focused question at a time. You should indicate the desired output for your sample input.

Comment: See my edit, I changed post

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try this, assuming your data is in a `data.frame` called `df`:

```
result <- unlist(lapply(sapply(df, function(x) which(x>2)), function(x) length(x)))
result
#Input_SNP     Set_1     Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5     Set_6 
#    2         1         0         1         0         2         1
```

In reality this is a 3 step process, first `result <- sapply(df, function(x) which(x>2)` will give you the following structure:

```
#List of 7
#$ Input_SNP: int [1:2] 4 6
#$ Set_1    : int 7
#$ Set_2    : int(0) 
#$ Set_3    : int 1
#$ Set_4    : int(0) 
#$ Set_5    : int [1:2] 3 6
#$ Set_6    : int 3
```

And this is inserted in a `lapply()` of the following form:

```
lapply(result, function(x) length(x))
```

For the following structure:

```
#List of 7
#$ Input_SNP: int 2
#$ Set_1    : int 1
#$ Set_2    : int 0
#$ Set_3    : int 1
#$ Set_4    : int 0
#$ Set_5    : int 2
#$ Set_6    : int 1
```

Finally this is unlisted for the final form.

If `Input_SNP` should not be part of the desired result, remove it from the `df` inside the `sapply()`, like so:

```
unlist(lapply(sapply(df[,-1], function(x) which(x>2)), function(x) length(x)))
#Set_1 Set_2 Set_3 Set_4 Set_5 Set_6 
#1     0     1     0     2     1
```

Finally for the proportions:

```
result/colSums(!is.na(df[,-1]))
#    Set_1     Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5     Set_6 
#0.1666667 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.2857143 0.1666667
```

Comment: This is a great start! But since my columns have arbitrary and random amounts of NA, it is useless to compare the total in each column that is over 2. That's why I need a percentage that is over 2. So 1/6, 0/5, 1/6, etc. How can I add this to what you have already written?

Comment: Check the edited answer, it's basically a restatement of @MrFlick 's answer (which also includes the histogram that you want). Another option in this case could be a barplot.

Comment: Can you get me the p-value for the Input_SNP column percentage on the distribution plot?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a histogram of the proportion of non-missing values >2, you can just do

```
hist(colMeans(as.matrix(df[,-1]) > 2, na.rm=TRUE))
```

The `df[,-1]` remove the `Index_SNP` column, and we use `colMeans` on the boolean values to get proportions.

[image]

Comment: That is what I want! But how can I adjust the bin size?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `?hist`

Comment: You're going to get best answer! But I need to know how to find my p=value for my colmean of column (Input_SNP) on that distrubtion!

Comment: p-value? What type of test are you doing? Where do you want to get a p-value from?

Comment: Null distribution is the histogram distribution. I guess I just want a z-score for the Input_SNP column percentage.

Comment: Also, is there a way to make them percentages instead of decimals. For example: 4 instead of 0.04. I was thinking of adding a 100* somewhere but don't know where to put it.