# Making a histogram distribution and then calculating a zscore in R

Tags: r, dataframe, distribution

I have a large data file that looks like:

```
Input_SNP   Set_1    Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5     Set_6
1.09        0.162    NA        2.312     1.876     0.12      0.812
0.687       NA       0.987     1.32      1.11      1.04      NA
NA          1.890    0.923     1.43      0.900     2.02      2.7
2.801       0.642    0.791     0.812     NA        0.31      1.60
1.33        1.33     NA        1.22      0.23      0.18      1.77
2.91        1.00     1.651     NA        1.55      3.20      0.99
1.00        2.31     0.89      1.13      1.25      0.12      1.55
```

And I would like to find the percentage of each column that is over 2 and not counting any of the NAs:

```
Input_SNP    Set_1     Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5     Set_6
0.33         0.166     0.000     0.166     0.000     0.286     0.166
```

I tried `mdd2 <- colMeans(as.matrix(mdd) > 2, na.rm=TRUE)` but it is not working. **HOW CAN I GET THE ABOVE OUTPUT?**

I would then like to make a histogram distribution of the values in Set_1 to Set_6. I have already done this with `hist(colMeans(as.matrix(df[,-1]) > 2, na.rm=TRUE))`

My next plan is to calculate a z-score for my Input_SNP percentage. I was thinking this could be done by

`pop_sd <- sd(my row name)*sqrt((row length -1)/(row length))`

`pop_mean <- mean(row)`

`zscore <- (Input_SNP percentage minus pop_mean)/pop_sd`

**THE ABOVE IS MY PSEUDO CODE ATTEMPT. HOW WOULD THIS BE DONE IN R?**

I would then like to print the z-score on the histogram:

I was thinking potentially with:
`jpeg("hist.jpg")`

`hist(colMeans(as.matrix(df[,-1]) > 2, na.rm=TRUE))`

`print(zscore)`

`dev.off()`

**IS THIS HOW PRINTING WORKS?**

Comment: You're basically re-asking most of what you already asked in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753882/r-distribution-plot-with-na-data-and-thresholds. What do you mean when you say you tried `mdd2 <- colMeans(as.matrix(mdd) > 2, na.rm=TRUE)` but *it isn't working*? What does "not working" mean exactly? You shoud really only ask one question at a time.

Comment: I store `data <- colMeans(as.matrix(mdd) > 2, na.rm=TRUE)` and then when  I do `head(data)` I only get the first 6 columns.

Answer (score 1):

There is an `is.na.data.frame` method that returns a logical object of the same dimensions as its argument that could be used (along with `!` to give its negation) in combination with colSums as you had intended.

```
colSums(df>2, na.rm=TRUE)/colSums(!is.na(df))
Input_SNP     Set_1     Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5     Set_6 
    0.333     0.167     0.000     0.167     0.000     0.286     0.167
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Is there a reason `colMeans(as.matrix(df) > 2, na.rm=TRUE)` wouldn't work? I'm annoyed that this question is so much like the previous but with even more questions added in.

Comment: Yeah, that works too :)  We are a bunch of over-thinkers

Comment: I didn't even try. Assumed that the OP had found something wrong with it.

Comment: It could just be `colMeans(df > 2, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: He does claim there is something wrong with it but I can't see anything that would cause that not to work but one of these others to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
over2<-colMeans(apply(as.matrix(ds), c(1,2), function(x) ifelse(is.na(x)||x<2, 0, 1)))
percent_over2 <- colSums(over2)/dim(over2)[1]
```

Comment: Your first code did not work. The NAs are messing with it. I have 100 columns in actuality and it is only returning 5 columns. And the column means are all messed up. I don't even want the mean of the column. I want the percentage of scores in each column that are over 2. Does that make sense? Same for the barplot